# How to get last Sunday's date?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, weekday

I need to show last Sunday's date in a cell for a weekly report that I'm creating on google sheets. I've been googling to find a solution and the closest I found is this:

```
=TODAY()+(7-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3))
```

But this gives next Monday's date. Any idea how to modify this to show last Sunday's date? Alternately, do you have another way to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you change the numbers? Don’t use google sheets so will let you test...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you're looking for would be:

```
=DATE(YY, MM, DD) - (WEEKDAY(DATE(YY, MM, DD)) - 1) - 7

// OR

=TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY()) - 1) - 7
```

Depending on what you take to be "last Sunday," you can simplify/factor this:

If you take "last Sunday" to mean, *"the Sunday which has most recently happened:"*

```
=DATE(A2,B2,C2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2,B2,C2)) + 1
```

If you take "last Sunday" to mean, *"the Sunday which took place during the previous week:"*

```
=DATE(A4,B4,C4) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A4,B4,C4)) - 6
```

---

Working through it:

```
=TODAY() - (WEEKDAY(TODAY()) - 1) - 7


 TODAY()
 // get today's date, ie. 22/11/2019

            WEEKDAY(TODAY())
            // get the current day of the week, ie. 6 (friday)

         -
         // take the first date and subtract that to rewind through the week,
         // ie. 16/11/2019 (last saturday, since saturday is 0)

                             - 1
                             // rewind back one less than the entire week
                             // ie. 17/11/2019 (this sunday)

                                  - 7
                                  // rewind back to the sunday before this
                                  // sunday, ie. 10/11/2019
```

Hopefully this explanation explains what the numbers at the end are doing. `+ 1` takes you from the Saturday of last week to the Sunday of the current week (what I would call "this Sunday"), and `- 6` takes you back through last week to what I would call "last Sunday."

---

**See here:**

[image: Google Sheets Example]

---

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()-6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), 
 TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()-6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), "ddd")="Sun")))
```

[image: 0]

---

if today is Sunday and you want still the last Sunday then:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TEXT(TODAY(), "ddd")="Sun", TODAY()-6, 
 TO_DATE(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()-6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), 
 TEXT(ROW(INDIRECT(VALUE(TODAY()-6)&":"&VALUE(TODAY()))), "ddd")="Sun"))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Using monday as 1 index, this will return the previous sunday or today if it is sunday

```
=if((7-WEEKDAY(today(),2))>0,today()-(7-(7-WEEKDAY(today(),2))),today()+(7-WEEKDAY(today(),2)))
```

One can select for other days of the week by changing the number "7" directly before "-WEEKDAY(today(),2)" in the three places that pattern exists.